# How can I activate a new gif, have it play for 5 seconds, then return to the previous gif in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a simple application using PySimpleGUI that shows a gif character in an "idle" animation and want to be able to change to a different gif animation when hitting a button, have the animation play for 5 seconds, then automatically switch back to the "idle" animation. I have been able to complete all of the above aside from the "play for 5 seconds, then automatically switch back to the 'idle' animation" piece.

Here is the code thus far:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# storing gifs as base64 
idle = b'[base64 encoded gif]'
wave = b'[base64 encoded gif]'
cheer = b'[base64 encoded gif]'
tipjar = b'[base64 encoded gif]'
cocktail = b'[base64 encoded gif]'
beer = b'[base64 encoded gif]'

# Putting all gifs into a list
gifs = [idle, wave, cheer, tipjar, cocktail, beer]

# Setting up the window and button layout
sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [[sg.Image(background_color='#00b140', key='-IMAGE-', pad=(0, 0), right_click_menu=[
                    '&Right', ['Settings', 'Exit']])],
          [sg.Button('!Wave'), sg.Button('!Cheer'), sg.Button('!TipJar'), sg.Button('!Cocktail'), sg.Button('!Beer')]]

window = sg.Window('Animated Avatar', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
image = window['-IMAGE-']

# Calling the first item in the gifs list
gif = gifs[0]

# Program loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    # Button click events to change the gif being presented
    elif event == '!Wave':
        gif = gifs[1]

    elif event == '!Cheer':
        gif = gifs[2]

    elif event == '!TipJar':
        gif = gifs[3]

    elif event == '!Cocktail':
        gif = gifs[4]

    elif event == '!Beer':
        gif = gifs[5]

    # Overall gif animation rules
    image.update_animation(gif, 500)
```

How can I complete the 5 second gif animation and return to idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're something wrong to view some GIF at this moment, so I add code here to open GIF by PIL.Image/PIL.ImageTk/PIL.ImageSequence.

It may take time to download GIFs from website and get each frame from GIF, you can do it before script running to save the time.

```py
import base64
import pathlib
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup_non_blocking("Wait for gif data ready ...", auto_close=True, auto_close_duration=2)

urls = {
    "Hi Baby":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_b87c9d99-d0a5-4d86-821b-4bf4d69765b1.gif',
    "Are You Serious":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_461fed8b-ee94-46bd-bfbf-4047bee4b615.gif',
    "Miss You":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_d8155620-10c0-4a48-b143-fb35d700fe80.gif',
    "I'm Borke":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_d79a57bd-c183-44fa-8969-ee710e766de7.gif',
    "I Kill You":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_f6178668-2bc7-4039-ae95-4d1815a3a554.gif',
    "Call Me":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_11f15a3f-eb9f-4cec-a799-8c6e882b182d.gif',
    "Oh My God":'https://bobble-animations.bobblekeyboard.net/previews/animation_preview_0edf207c-8189-411f-b745-5b90f92cb37d.gif',
}
idle = "Hi Baby"

for key, url in urls.items():
    filename = f'{key}.gif'
    if not pathlib.Path(filename).is_file():
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urls[key]).content)

# --Following code should be called after window finalized or sg.popup called.--
gifs = {}
for key, url in urls.items():
    filename = f'{key}.gif'
    images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame) for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(Image.open(filename))]
    gifs[key] = (len(images), images)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
layout = [
    [sg.Image(filename=f'{idle}.gif', key='-IMAGE-')],
    [sg.Button(key, expand_x=True) for key in urls if key !=idle],
]
window = sg.Window('Animation', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
image = window['-IMAGE-']

show, gif, index, frames, count = idle, gifs[idle][1], 0, len(gifs[idle][1]), 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event in gifs:
        gif, index, frames, count = gifs[event][1], 0, len(gifs[event][1]), 0

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        count += 1
        if count == 20: # 2 seconds
            show, gif, index, frames, count = idle, gifs[idle][1], 0, len(gifs[idle][1]), 0
        image.update(data=gif[index])
        index = (index + 1) % frames

window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question. I used perf_counter() as a timer which counts up from zero. Once it hits a set integer, the gif is changed back to the "idle" animation. Each time a button is activated, the timer is reset to zero to count back up.

```
# Calling the first item in the gifs list and setting up a timer variable
gif = gifs[0]
timer = time.perf_counter()

# Program loop
while True:

    # Make the timer count up and change back to idle gif when 5 seconds elapses
    elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - timer)
    if elapsed >= 5:
        gif = gifs[0]
        timer = time.perf_counter()

    # Button click events to change the gif being presented and reset counter to zero
    elif event == '!Wave':
        timer = time.perf_counter()
        gif = gifs[1]

    elif event == '!Cheer':
        gif = gifs[2]
        timer = time.perf_counter()
```

If anyone has a better way to do it or suggestions on how to clean up my code please let me know.